# Frontend users with Bolt 4

Tags: frontend, content-management-system, bolt-cms, bolt

I moved to Bolt 4 (from Bolt 3.7) and would like to implement front-end user to give them access to private contents of the website. Previously, I used the extension [BoltAuth/Auth](https://market.bolt.cm/view/boltauth/auth), which worked like a charm.

Now in Bolt 4, there is no easy way like in Bolt 3.x to install an extension from the back-end page. I [found out](https://docs.bolt.cm/4.0/extensions/introduction) I could use `composer` to do so, but I run in the following problem:

```
> composer require "boltauth/auth:3.0.1"

[InvalidArgumentException]
Could not find a matching version of package boltauth/auth. Check the package 
spelling, your version constraint and that the package is available in a stability 
which matches your minimum-stability (stable).
```

Either I do something wrong, or the extension is not compatible with Bolt 4.1.

Could someone tell me if there is a way to make this extension work? Or alternatives for front-end user management?

EDIT: I'm now using the `bolt/users` [extension](https://github.com/bolt/users) as it can be used to add a `ROLE_MEMBERS` and let users login for the frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, unfortunately the architecture for plugins (mainly driven by the move from Silex to Symfony) changed completely between 3.x and 4.x and it's not really feasible to release new 4.x compatible versions.

So for now there won't likely be updates to BoltAuth. It may be worth joining the Slack community and seeing if any other developers are working on 4.x compatible solutions to the client login scenarios.